# Bootstrap 3: Centering and pinning footers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4unwqL9/) that contains full code.

As you can see, the footer consists of three distinct sections:

1. 4 columns of links
2. A `<hr/>`
3. A copyright notice
4. Links to the privacy policy and terms of service

I want to:

- Center the footer (as you can see, currently it's lop-sided slightly to the right) and my attempt via `center-block` does nothing
- As you can see, the footer is pushed right up against the bottom of the jumbotron. I want this to be a "sticky" footer, such that it is always pinned to the bottom of the viewable screen, even if there isn't a lot of content on the page (e.g., just a jumbotron).

I can get this stickiness by changing adding a `position: absolute;` definition to the `.footer` rule like so:

```
.footer {
    color: rgb(176,205,249);
    background: rgb(12,66,144);
    border-top: solid 5px rgb(176,205,249);

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

However when I do this, the footer breaks out of the container and the browser displays a horizontal scrollbar - not desirable. Any ideas how I can accomplish both my objectives here?

Comment: Your footer height is not 60px so that's not going to work. It would require jQuery to do this unless you want to change the structure of your html. But first, the html in your footer and the css was so completely wrong. Nested grids (unecessary and implemented wrong) strange positioning and on and on. First is to clean it up then implement the jQuery. Here's a cleaned up version of the footer. Notice the lack of nested grid classes among other things. http://jsbin.com/leweza/1/ -- the css changed too. Edit: http://jsbin.com/leweza/1/edit?html,css,js

Comment: When the html/css is correctly done, then: http://blog.mojotech.com/responsive-dynamic-height-sticky-footers/

Comment: Thanks @Christina (+1 for both) - However one followup question: you say that the sticky footer needs to be implemented in JavaScript, but I was actually hoping to model my footer from this [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). The CSS for that is [this page](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/style.css), but I can't figure out how to make it work with your `jsbin` example. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, when you learn how to use it and read the css it indicates that the footer has a fixed height of 155px (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css) and that is used. You don't have a height since it's a fluid grid -- when a user has a smaller or wider viewport the height of the footer is variable. jQuery is used to calculate that and adjust the styles accordingly on resize. Even bootstrap's implementation is fixed at 60px. I use the jQuery all the time because I have 4 columns and the height changes based on how the text wraps and my padding is in percentages so it's fluid.

Comment: Thanks again @Christina (+1) - starting to make sense. I guess I'm a little lost with how I can get my footer to be sticky. What jQuery would I have to implement? What CSS rules would I need to add? Thanks again!

Comment: Use the link I posted on the second of this thread. It's the one I use.